# Register button in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I made a login page in CakePHP and need to add a register button, this is the code of \View\Users\login.ctp:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-content">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('logo1.png', array('alt' => 'fivassist Logo')); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h2>Bem-vindo!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>E-mail:</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', 
                        array('label' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
                </li>
                <li><label>Password:</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', 
                        array('label' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end login-form -->
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('id' => 'login-bt')); ?>
        <a href="#" id="forgot">Esqueceu-se da sua password?</a>

            <?php echo $this->Form->button('Register'); ?>

    </div> <!-- end login-content -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

How i redirect the register button to /user/add.ctp?

Can you help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point your form to your "register" action: I would advise making this action separate from your "New User" action- sometimes you want to have different logic.

This should submit to `/users/register`. Note the parameters on `$this->Form->create`:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false,'placeholder' => 'Email'));
echo $this->Form->input('pwd', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false,  'placeholder' => 'Password'));
echo $this->Form->input('pwd_repeat', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false,  'placeholder' => 'Password'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Register', array('class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

I'd also suggest you read the [docs for HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html), they can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to when click button login that will submit to action login and click button register it's submit to action users/add ?
if so that you can use javascript or jQuery

```
$(function () {
        // when click button login
        $('#btn-login').on('click', function () {
            // #form: id of form, you should named it
            $('#form').atrr('action', 'login'); 
        });
        // when click button register
        $('#btn-register').on('click', function () {
            $('#form').atrr('action', 'register');
        });
        $('#form').submit();
});
```

And if you want to click button register it's will redirect to view add.ctp
So that you can use HtmlHelper

```
echo $this->Html->link('Register', array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'btn-register', 'id' => 'btn-register', 'escape' => false));
```

and then you define css for btn-register

```
.btn-register {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```